# I want to decrease my stock amount by the delivery button in MongoDb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

How do i decrease stock in my react app by a delivery button which is connected in MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the Delivered button, you will reduce the quantity one by one, then you will send that value to the backend and update it in the database.
Increase in the same way.

as like...

const stockQuantity = parseInt(products?.quantity)
const newStockQuantity = stockQuantity - 1;

then

fetch(url, {
method: 'PUT', // or 'PUT'
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify(
{
quantity: newStockQuantity,
}
),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
console.log('Success:', data);
toast('Your Product Deliver successfully')
setIsReload(!reload)
})

Answer (score 0):

const delevary = e => {

```
    const quantity = product?.quantity
    const updateItem = {quantity}
    const url = `http://localhost:7000//${id}`;
    fetch(url,{
        method : 'PUT',
        headers : {
            'content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(updateItem)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then (result =>{
        console.log(result)
        setIsreload(!isReload)
        // setItems(result);
    })
        
    
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).